# dynamically added checkboxes in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added check boxes dynamically to a panel. now how can i get a alert message with "you have checked 1 or 2 or 3....". when check boxes get selected??

```
CheckBox[] premiumticket = new CheckBox[50];
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


     var panel1 = new Panel()
    {

        Size = new Size(600, 70),
        Location = new Point(20, 130),
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    };




        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
           premiumticket[i]=new CheckBox();
           premiumticket[i].Text=(i+1).ToString();
           premiumticket[i].Name=(i+1).ToString();
           premiumticket[i].Location=new Point(x,y);
           panel1.Controls.Add(premiumticket[i]);

           x = x - 55;
           if (x < 55)
           {
               y = y + 20;
               x = 550;
           }
        }

        x = 550; y = 10;

        Controls.Add(panel1);  
   }
```

Comment: here there is no button if we click one checkbox it shows that you have checked (the name of the check box) checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Add an event-handler to each CheckBox:

```
public void Checkbox_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;

    MessageBox.Show( cb.Name + " was clicked!");
}

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    premiumticket[i] = new CheckBox();
    premiumticket[i].OnCheckChanged += new EventHandler( Checkbox_CheckedChange );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically Create events for Each Checkbox and put ur alert code on it

Comment: I don't have another way of contacting you, so I'll enter a comment here.  *DO NOT* add pipe characters (`|`) separating columns of data for code blocks with the `R` tag.  That is vandalism of the data.  These bogus pipe characters prevent pasting the text into the `R` interpreter.  I don't know how your edit of a question with this vandalism passed a recent review (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071723/calculate-means-of-specific-columns) but it should not have.  I rolled back the edit.

Comment: ok @MatthewLundberg i am sorry if i did anything wrong thanks for your advice i keep it in my mind

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your for loop:

```
premiumticket[i].OnCheckChanged += new EventHandler( premiumTicketChanged );
```

Checkbox toggled handler:

```
public void premiumTicketChanged (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ticketCount = premiumticket.Count(c => c.Checked);
    MessageBox.Show( string.Format("You have checked {0} checkboxes....", ticketCount));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var checkBox = new CheckBox { ID = "WCCheckBox" + item.ItemID.ToString(), ItemID = item.ItemID, Checked = item.UserValue == "1", CssClass = "wounditem" };
```

Your implementation may be another.

Answer (score 0):

After you add dynamically a control you can use AddHandler to manage the events of this control.
Remember set the checkbox autopostback property to true.

Comment: autopostback is an ASP.Net concept. WinForms is being used in the above question.

Comment: It`s true. I misstook the context, sorry.