# Calculate means of specific columns

Tags: r

```
C1<-c(3,2,4,4,5)
C2<-c(3,7,3,4,5)
C3<-c(5,4,3,6,3)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"),C1=C1,C2=C2,C3=C3)

DF
  ID Type C1 C2 C3
1  A    1  3  3  5
2  B    2  2  7  4
3  C    1  4  3  3
4  D    2  4  4  6
5  E    2  5  5  3
```

How do I calculate the mean of each column grouping by Type and ignore the ID column? Namely:

```
Type    C1   C2   C3
   1  3.50 3.00 4.00
   2  3.67 5.00 4.33
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no "Type" in your sample data, but this is a pretty straightforward `aggregate` task.

Answer (score 2):

Create the data with the `Type` column:

```
DF <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='  ID Type C1 C2 C3
1  A    1  3  3  5
2  B    2  2  7  4
3  C    1  4  3  3
4  D    2  4  4  6
5  E    2  5  5  3')
```

Then, with the knowledge that the `ID` column is at position 1, a simple application of `aggregate` gets you what you want:

```
aggregate(.~Type, data=DF[-1], FUN=mean)
  Type       C1       C2       C3
1    1 3.500000 3.000000 4.000000
2    2 3.666667 5.333333 4.333333
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually my question wasn't complete, but I figured it out from your answers! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Some other approaches:

```
### plyr was written with this type of problem in mind
library(plyr)
ddply(DF[-1], .(Type), colMeans)

### staying in base; these are more unwieldly than `aggregate`
t(sapply(split(DF[-c(1,2)], DF$Type), colMeans))
### `ave` also written for similar problems; however will replace all elements 
### by vector average (mean) so need to use `unique` afterwards:
unique(with(DF, ave(C1, Type)))
with(DF,
     lapply(lapply(DF[-c(1,2)], ave, Type), unique)
     )

### faster and scales well on large datasets
library(data.table)
DFt <- as.data.table(DF)
DFt[, list(mean(C1), mean(C2), mean(C3)), by=Type]
```